# Non-Rooted Android Emulators for Mac

Tags: android-emulator, unrooting, macos

I was running some apps on Android Emulators for Mac.
But one day they stopped working. The error said that I was using a rooted device.
I tried to unroot the emulators but they all did not work.

So I was wondering if anybody could tell me Non-Rooted Android Emulators or ways to unroot emulators completely

These are the emulators I used to use:
Genymotion, Andy, Bluestacks